# Text pointer showing on checkbox, radio and submit elements (web-kit)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a site and for some reason, when I tab between form elements in web-kit based browsers, it shows the text (I-beam) cursor in the top-left of checkbox, radio and submit input elements. Setting the cursor to pointer or default in CSS has no effect.

I am custom styling the checkbox and radio inputs with opacity 0 positioned over the top of my styled elements but there is nothing really special going on with the submit buttons (just usual bg graphic styling.

Is this something anyone else has had before?
Can anyone point to a possible cause.

Inspecting the DOM in chrome shows the element as using the cursor I define, but my eyes tell a different story.

Comment: Please post the code. Preferably, a minimal self-contained version that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately there is too much code even when most things have been eliminated. I ended up solving it by adding **-webkit-user-modify: read-only;** to the inputs (submit, checkbox & radio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by adding **-webkit-user-modify: read-only;** to the inputs (submit, checkbox & radio)